# How can I delete form field data in django after submit

Tags: django, forms

I'm working on a django project where during registration, a user can submit a code to get special discounts. The validation of the discount codes is already working nicely, but I'm missing one beautifying aspect: After the user submits an invalid code I want to empty out the input field; i.e.:

```
def validate_code(value):
  # check code for validity or raise ValidationError

class CodeForm(forms.Form):
  code = forms.CharField(validators=[validate_code])

# in my views.py
def code_verification_view(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CodeForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      # proceed with given code
    else:
      # modify form to return an empty html input for the code field
      # this is where I'm stuck
      form.fields['code'].value = ''

  # ... render the form in a template
```

The end result should be a form with an empty input field, but the validation errors showing. The behavior should be similar to how password input fields are emptied if the form verification fails.

**EDIT: I solved the problem, but in a very hacky way:**
see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46564834/8572938
I'd appreciate a proper solution that does not rely on accessing protected members of the form.

Comment: If you managed to solve the problem for now you should add an answer to this post and for example link to it with a note that it works but you dislike it :)

Comment: See the solution to [Clear all Form Fields on Validation Error in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57264601/5916915)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way that works, but it's quite dirty:

```
old_form = CodeForm(request.POST)
form = CodeForm()
if old_form.is_valid():
  # ...
else:
  form._errors = old_form._errors

# pass form into the rendering context
```

This way, I get a clean form with the preserved errors. 
While it does the job, it is clearly an ugly hack.

Comment: did you try my solution?

Comment: Here's a [clean solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57264601/5916915).

Answer (score 3):

the key is to reset form variable

```
form = CodeForm(None)
```

in your code

```
def code_verification_view(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
     form = CodeForm(request.POST)
  if form.is_valid():
     # proceed with given code
  else:
     form = CodeForm(None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a field validation in your form definition:

```
class CodeForm(forms.Form):
    code = forms.CharField(validators=[validate_code])

    def clean_code(self):
        code = self.cleaned_data(code)
        error = # some of your process
        if error:
            self.fields['code'] = None
            raise forms.ValidationError('...')
        else:
            return code
```

And remove the `else` part in your view, instead you want to do something else. If you just want to display the form with error, the `raise forms.ValidationError` will do it.

You can in django form add a `clean_<field_name>` to control each field as you like.

More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/validation/)

Comment: If I raise the error, the input field in the form will still hold the value the user entered. I want to clear the text in the CharField's widget if an invalid code is entered.

Comment: You can clear the field value doing self.fields['code'] = None

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. The fields attribute is a list of django Field objects. Putting a string there throws an exception later on.

Comment: a string? I put ```None```

Comment: That still does not work.
I just want to show an empty input in html, not remove a field from the form.

Answer (score 0):

Just render your template, if your form is not valid, it will show error, In case if it is valid process your data

```
def code_verification_view(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CodeForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        // process your data
    else:
        form.data['field'] = None

  return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})
```

Comment: I don't want to just show an error message, I want to have an empty input box plus the error message if there is an error. 
The code you suggested will still keep the invalid string the user has entered.

Comment: Already tried this. Unfortunately, form.data is immutable at this point